# When would a StaticLayout return a height of 0?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a method which returns the height of a `StaticLayout` (to be used downstream). In a rare case, it is returning `0` as the height, which makes dependent functions crash. What could be causing a result of 0? The text passed is "T". The mEventTextPaint is set to a valid size. Any ideas?

```
private int getTextLineHeight(String text, float widthPerDay) {
        StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(text, mEventTextPaint, (int) (widthPerDay - mEventPadding * 2), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
        return textLayout.getHeight() / textLayout.getLineCount();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you getting your layout height so early try this code

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
     // get height here
        return true;
        }
    });
```